# macOS 10.12.6 Sierra keychain has stopped saving passwords, how to repair?

Tags: macos, keychain

Within the last few weeks I have noticed that my system has stopped or cannot save passwords. Outlook, iCloud, and other GUI apps ask for them every single time. Attached is a picture from SequelPro when attempting to save a password.

How can I diagnose / repair the Keychain?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to High Sierra ultimately resolved this. It simply began working again.

Answer (score 0):

> **Warning:** macOS no longer supports Keychain repair, instead it just creates a new default Keychain, which will result in a loss of all saved passwords.

1. Quit all open applications that might be using Keychain including Sequel.
2. To try to repair the Keychain use Finder to go to `/Applications/Utilities`.

*You can also <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> from Finder to open that folder directly.*

2. Launch Keychain Access.
3. Then go to the menu bar and select Keychain Access > Preferences.
4. Click "Reset My Default Keychain"

*Follow any instructions beyond this and retest those applications.*

Comment: I tried this, but it just say "Unable to obtain authorization for this operation."

Comment: I recently had a stubborn keychain. I've solved this in the past usually with more grace, but this last time I simply had to completely delete it start over. Sad. Another neglected component of the Apple Desktop Platform.